# How to hide the clock from Android screen?

Tags: applications, launcher, customization

There is always a clock on the upper right corner of the screen? It is always visible, unless some app is running in full-screen mode. How to hide this clock, so that it appears only when the user wants it to?

Another solution could be to make the screen always run in full-screen mode, so that the clock is visible only when one drags the screen down.

Is this possible? Especially on a non-rooted phone...

Thank you.

Comment: On Android 6.0+, enable SystemUI Tuner and find the option inside; some manufacturers might have removed the tuner, or messed with its options, though. Otherwise I don't know of a solution without root.

Comment: For some (all?) Sony Xperia phones there is a "system icons" settings menu, through which one can select which icons to display in the status bar. One of the configureable "icons" is called "Time" -  if unchecked in the settings the clock is hidden from the status bar.

Comment: Sadly, i have Motorola with android 5 :-(